# Is there the equivalent of to_markdown to read data?

Tags: python, pandas

With pandas 1.0.0 the use of `.to_markdown()` to show the content of a dataframe in this forum in [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) is going to proliferate. Is there a convenient way to load the data back into a dataframe? Maybe an option to `.from_clipboard(markdown=True)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the answers so far read the data from the clipboard. They all require the data to be in a string. This led me to look into the source code of `pandas.read_clipboard()`, and lo and behold, the method internally uses `pandas.read_csv()`, and passes all arguments to it. This automatically leads to the following solution:

```py
t = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1], "b":[2, 3]}).to_markdown()                                                                                                                                                    
print(t)
```

```
|    |   a |   b |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 |   2 |
|  1 |   1 |   3 |
```

Mark the table and copy it to the clipboard (Ctrl-C on Windows). Building on the above answers:

```py
pd.read_clipboard(sep="|", header=0, index_col=1, skipinitialspace=True).dropna(
    axis=1, how="all"
).iloc[1:]
```

The next step would be to integrate this into https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/ so it can be easily called with a `markdown=True` parameter.

Answer (score 27):

You can read markdown tables (or any structured text table) with the pandas `read_table` function:

Let's create a sample markdown table:

```py
pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1], "b":[2, 3]}).to_markdown()
```

```html
|    |   a |   b |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 |   2 |
|  1 |   1 |   3 |
```

As you can see, this is just a structured text table where the delimiters are pipes, there's a lot of whitespace, there are null columns on the left-most and right-most, and there's a header underline that must be dropped.

```py
pd
  # Read a markdown file, getting the header from the first row and inex from the second column
  .read_table('df.md', sep="|", header=0, index_col=1, skipinitialspace=True)
  # Drop the left-most and right-most null columns 
  .dropna(axis=1, how='all')
  # Drop the header underline row
  .iloc[1:]   

   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  3
```

Comment: If you have a table in pretty format it is likely that you will have whitespace in the column names. You can use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` to get rid of that.

Comment: I see that I can parse a markdown table back into a dataframe, but this does not solve the part of getting the data into Python from the clipboard, no? In your example you also read the markdown text from a file. It would be great to be able to do everything in one step.

Answer (score 5):

This takes care of removing all whitespaces from the values and column names (so be careful if you have whitesapce that you want to keep in your values):

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

md_table = pd.DataFrame({"a": [3, 10000], "b":[2222, 3]}).to_markdown()
print(md_table)
```

```
# The white space on both columns and values need to be removed
|    |     a |    b |
|---:|------:|-----:|
|  0 |     3 | 2222 |
|  1 | 10000 |    3 |
```

---

```py
# Paste in your table and assign it to a variable
md_table_string = """
|    |     a |    b |
|---:|------:|-----:|
|  0 |     3 | 2222 |
|  1 | 10000 |    3 |
"""

pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(md_table_string.replace(' ', '')),  # Get rid of whitespaces
    sep='|',
    index_col=1
).dropna(
    axis=1,
    how='all'
).iloc[1:]
```

```
       a     b
0      3  2222
1  10000     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregating the helpful information in answers and comments, while using a regex to remove formatting spaces in each markdown cells.

```
import re
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO


def read_markdown_table(table_str: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Read markdown table from string and return pandas DataFrame."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184953/
    cleaned_table_str = re.sub(r'(?<=\|)( *[\S ]*? *)(?=\|)', lambda match: match.group(0).strip(), table_str)
    df = pd.read_table(StringIO(cleaned_table_str), sep="|", header=0, skipinitialspace=True) \
           .dropna(axis=1, how='all') \
           .iloc[1:]
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() 
    return df
```

Comment: There is something very wrong with this function. It is reading the second and third columns as having the same values. In the table text, however, they have separate values.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found the same issue, so I made a library `mdpd`.

It may hold up for your cases.

```py
# pip install mdpd
# https://pypi.org/project/mdpd/
import mdpd

df = mdpd.from_md("""
+------------+-------+
| id         | score |
+------------+-------+
| 1          | 15    |
| 2          | 11    |
| 3          | 11    |
| 4          | 20    |
+------------+-------+
""")

print(df)
#   id score
# 0  1    15
# 1  2    11
# 2  3    11
# 3  4    20


df2 = mdpd.from_md(df.to_markdown(index=False))
#   id score
# 0  1    15
# 1  2    11
# 2  3    11
# 3  4    20

print((df == df2).all().all())
# True
```

I hope this library your helps.