# Converting data in array format to Columns : Create new column from column headers

Tags: python, excel

I have the Memory Usage Data for different users IDs across dates in excel.

The sample table is shared below
User ID (A-E) is mentioned as a column header.

Input Data having memory usage for different IDs

| Date\UserID | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/20/2020 |  | 4 |  |  |  |
| 1/21/2020 | 5 |  | 3 |  |  |
| 1/22/2020 |  |  |  |  | 11 |
| 1/23/2020 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/24/2020 |  | 7 |  |  |  |
| 1/25/2020 |  |  |  | 8 | 6 |

I want to convert the column header data which is ID to a new column.

The expected output should look like this

| Date | User ID | Memory Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/20/2020 | B | 4 |
| 1/21/2020 | A | 5 |
| 1/21/2020 | C | 3 |
| 1/22/2020 | E | 11 |
| 1/24/2020 | B | 7 |
| 1/25/2020 | D | 8 |
| 1/25/2020 | E | 6 |

I've tried using various combinations of excel functions but it is not working. Please suggest a way to perform the same using excel or python code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems you want the [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) or [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) methods. This is also called unpivoting. In Excel you can [unpivot using Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function in Pandas to unpivot the data. In Excel, the same thing can be done by [unpivoting in Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098).

You didn't post any Python code but luckily, it's possible to use [read_clipboard](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) to read a Markdown table and split the lines. This is shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72414429/134204):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_clipboard(sep="|", header=0, index_col=1, skipinitialspace=True).dropna(
    axis=1, how="all"
).iloc[1:]
```

After that, `melt` unpivots the data, using the column names as the variable named `UserID` and the column values as the value column `Memory Usage`. Rows with nulls are dropped before the dataframe is sorted and the index renamed.

```
df1=pd.melt(df1,
            var_name='UserID',
            value_name='Memory Usage',
            ignore_index=False)
df1=df1.dropna().sort_index()
df1.index=df1.index.rename('Date')
```

The result is :

| Date | UserID | Memory Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/20/2020 | B | 4 |
| 1/21/2020 | A | 5 |
| 1/21/2020 | C | 3 |
| 1/22/2020 | E | 11 |
| 1/24/2020 | B | 7 |
| 1/25/2020 | D | 8 |
| 1/25/2020 | E | 6 |